# Copy data from one sheet that lies between two time frames, to multiple other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to automate something as much as possible.

Essentially I am looking to do the following:

A) In column AR on the "Details" tab, determine if times lie between 12:01am and 8:59am, 9:00 am and 11:59 am, 12:00pm and 4:59pm, 5:00 pm and 7:59pm and 8:00 pm and 12:00am.

B) Once I have determined each set, I need to copy only the rows that matched, but only up to column AQ to a different sheet for each result.

Essentially >

- Determine 12:01 am - 7:59 am and copy A:AQ for those items to Early
- Determine 8:00 am - 11:59am and copy A:AQ for those items  to Morning
- Determine 12:00 pm - 4:59 pm and copy A:AQ for those items  to
  Afternoon
- Determine 5:00 pm - 7:59 pm and copy A:AQ for those items 
  to Drive Time
- Determine 8:00pm - 12:00 am and copy A:AQ for those
  items to Night

I can't seem to get the If selection correct.

---

I'm curious, in your code.. there are tabs after Evening (Sorry, it is Evening, I called it Night Originally).  Would this cause issues?  It seems like it works perfectly as far as the "Early" tab.  But it doesn't touch any of the other tabs at all.  Seems like it stops cycling.  There is plenty of data that matches the other tabs in Details.  So I feel like we are almost there, but just missing one essentialy piece.  Thanks for sticking with me Tony!

What I've tried is below

Current Code

```html
Option Explicit
Sub CopyByTime()

  Const RowDtlDataFirst As Long = 2

  Dim HourCrnt As Long
  Dim InxSht As Long
  Dim Limit() As Variant
  Dim RowDtlCrnt As Long
  Dim RowDtlLast As Long
  Dim RowDestNext() As Long
  Dim ShtDest() As Variant

  ' * ShtDest names the five sheets
  ' * For the first four elements, Limit(N) is the maximum hour for
  '   ShtDest(N).  Any row not copied to one of the first four sheets
  '   is copied to the last sheet.
  ShtDest = Array("Early", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Drive Time", "Evening")
  Limit = Array(9, 12, 15, 20)
  ReDim RowDestNext(0 To UBound(ShtDest))

  ' * Find last used row in each destination sheet and set next row to one more.
  ' * You start copy at row 2 and use the same variable for all destination
  '   sheets. This have a different variable for each sheet and adds new data
  '   under any existing data.  This is what I would want.  Adjust to your
  '   requirements.
  For InxSht = 0 To UBound(ShtDest)
    With Worksheets(ShtDest(InxSht))
      RowDestNext(InxSht) = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
  Next

  With Worksheets("Detail")
    ' First last row with a value in the data column.
    RowDtlLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For RowDtlCrnt = RowDtlDataFirst To RowDtlLast
      HourCrnt = Hour(.Cells(RowDtlCrnt, "AX").Value)
      For InxSht = 0 To UBound(ShtDest) - 1
        If HourCrnt < Limit(InxSht) Then
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      ' If HourCrnt is less than one of the values in Limit, the For-Loop
      ' will have been exited with InxSht identifying the required sheet.
      ' If HourCrnt is not less than one of the values in Limit, InxSht
      ' will be one more than the For-Loop's end value = UBound(ShtDest) -1 + 1

      .Range(.Cells(RowDtlCrnt, "A"), .Cells(RowDtlCrnt, "AQ")).Copy _
         Destination:=Worksheets(ShtDest(InxSht)).Cells(RowDestNext(InxSht), "A")
      RowDestNext(InxSht) = RowDestNext(InxSht) + 1

    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Issue was resolved by code below. What ended up happening was that there was residual data in the other sheets, so it determined the first "clear" line was around the row 2000 mark.  Once I figured this out, it worked beautifully.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update in response to comment of 2014-12-15 20:46:36Z and revised question**

*I'm curious, in your code.. there are tabs after Evening (Sorry, it is Evening, I called it Night Originally). Would this cause issues?*  I do not understand; what tabs after Evening/Night?

*I made the sample a lot smaller than the actual document. I was attempting to provide a mock up of the actual sheet I was using minus all the extra.* I understand trying to remove complexity that conceals the true question.  My confusion is that in the question you refer to columns A to AQ.  In the third comment you refer to column K and columns A:G.

*… stops working after the "Early" sheet, which seems like it is not continuing the loop.* My code does not do "Early" then "Morning" the "Afternoon" so I do not see how it can fail after the “Early” sheet.

My code works as I intended with my data.  Either my data does not match yours or my understanding of your requirement is faulty.

My code does not clear down worksheets "Early", "Morning", "Afternoon", "DriveTime" or "Night"; it adds to the bottom of any existing data.  This misunderstanding is easily fixed.  You say clear columns A:G.  What about columns H onwards?  It is possible to only clear selected columns but it is as easy to clear all columns.  Is there data in columns H onwards you want to retain?

I have my date and times in column A rather than column AR.  Again this is an easily fixed misunderstanding.

The code works down the "Detail" worksheet from row 2 to the last row with a value in column A.  This may not matter but perhaps it should be switched to column AR.

For each row, the loop extracts the hour from the date/time and then uses the arrays ShtDest and Limit to classify the time:

```
Array index      0       1         2           3           4
ShtDest        Early   Morning   Afternoon   DriveTime   Night
Limit            8       12       15          20
```

The classification is:

- If Hour < Limit(0) then destination worksheet is ShtDest(0) = "Early"
- ElseIf Hour < Limit(1) then destination worksheet is ShtDest(1) = "Morning"
- ElseIf Hour < Limit(2) then destination worksheet is ShtDest(2) = "Afternoon"
- ElseIf Hour < Limit(3) then destination worksheet is ShtDest(3) "DriveTime"
- Else destination worksheet is ShtDest(4) = "Night"

Columns A:AQ of the row in Detail are then copied to the next free row in the destination worksheet.

There may be better ways of achieving this result but I thought this was the simplest.

The above describes what the code is supposed to do and what it does on my laptop with my data.  Please explain in greater detail what is happening on your computer with mu data.

**Original posting**

I am not sure what you are attempting with your tests but I am sure you misunderstand how Excel holds dates and times.  VBA can set a date with a literal of the form #mm/dd/yy# but that is not how Excel holds a date.

It is not relevant to my solution but Excel holds dates and times as Doubles.  The integer part is the number of days since 1900. The fraction part is SecondsSinceMidnight / SecondsInADay.  Try creating a column of dates then formatting them as numbers.  Or try to opposite.  Once Excel has stored a number or date, it only knows which it is by looking at the number format.

I think my approach is adequately explained within the macro but do come back with questions if anything is unclear.

I created a workbook with worksheets “Detail”, “Early”, “Morning” and so on.

I filled worksheet “Detail” with data so:

[image: Worksheet Detail]

The date/times were created by adding dates in the range 1 to 9 December and times in the range 00:00:00 to 23:51:00 and then sorting into ascending sequence.  Columns B to AQ were filled with values that are Row number + Column number so I could match source and destination data.

In each of the destination worksheets I placed the word “Existing” in column A to represent existing data.  This is the worksheet “Afternoon”:

[image: Worksheet Afternoon before the macro is run]

After running the macro, the worksheet “Afternoon” looked like:

[image: Worksheet Afternoon after the macro is run]

The images are not as clear as I would like.  I will attempt to create some better images then update this answer,

I believe this macro is what you seek:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyByTime()

  Const RowDtlDataFirst As Long = 2

  Dim HourCrnt As Long
  Dim InxSht As Long
  Dim Limit() As Variant
  Dim RowDtlCrnt As Long
  Dim RowDtlLast As Long
  Dim RowDestNext() As Long
  Dim ShtDest() As Variant

  ' * ShtDest names the five sheets
  ' * For the first four elements, Limit(N) is the maximum hour for
  '   ShtDest(N).  Any row not copied to one of the first four sheets
  '   is copied to the last sheet.
  ShtDest = Array("Early", "Morning", "Afternoon", "DriveTime", "Night")
  Limit = Array(8, 12, 15, 20)
  ReDim RowDestNext(0 To UBound(ShtDest))

  ' * Find last used row in each destination sheet and set next row to one more.
  ' * You start copy at row 2 and use the same variable for all destination
  '   sheets. This have a different variable for each sheet and adds new data
  '   under any existing data.  This is what I would want.  Adjust to your
  '   requirements.
  For InxSht = 0 To UBound(ShtDest)
    With Worksheets(ShtDest(InxSht))
      RowDestNext(InxSht) = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
  Next

  With Worksheets("Detail")
    ' First last row with a value in the data column.
    RowDtlLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For RowDtlCrnt = RowDtlDataFirst To RowDtlLast
      HourCrnt = Hour(.Cells(RowDtlCrnt, "A").Value)
      For InxSht = 0 To UBound(ShtDest) - 1
        If HourCrnt < Limit(InxSht) Then
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      ' If HourCrnt is less than one of the values in Limit, the For-Loop
      ' will have been exited with InxSht identifying the required sheet.
      ' If HourCrnt is not less than one of the values in Limit, InxSht
      ' will be one more than the For-Loop's end value = UBound(ShtDest) -1 + 1

      .Range(.Cells(RowDtlCrnt, "A"), .Cells(RowDtlCrnt, "AQ")).Copy _
         Destination:=Worksheets(ShtDest(InxSht)).Cells(RowDestNext(InxSht), "A")
      RowDestNext(InxSht) = RowDestNext(InxSht) + 1

    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking if I am around?  I will check for new messages every 30 to 60 minutes for the next 7 to 8 hours.

Comment: Blasted site and it's "Enter means submit" :-)

Hey There Tony,

The above looks very elegant.  I think I am missing something however.  I get a "Runtime Error 9:  Subscript out of range" for the line "With Worksheets(ShtDest(InxSht))"

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume it's due to the fact that you didn't have my actual data to work off of.

[link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byh-lISZ2FniaDZySGhoeWo0aElWV1VlR25tcmMxQVhUVFVr/edit?usp=docslist_api)

This is a sample (I stripped out everything sensetive) that gives you an idea of how I'm set up.

Comment: The purpose of the coding / doc is to provide a summary of results (Column K) on another page.  Each worksheet is set up in time frame and the summary is calculating based on date & time from each sheet.

Ideally it would clear the row 2 A:G down completely each time on all sheets other than Detail to remove old data.

Then it would simply take from 6am - 8:59am from column G and copy that over to Early, 9:00 - 11:59am to morning and so on.

I hope that helps..  and THANK YOU.  I know it's a bit of a pain, but I'm learning every day and it's people like you that make it possible!

Comment: Sorry for the ton of extra comments.. apparently there is a rather short character limit on these.

Comment: I am working on another two questions.  I will get back to you but it will not be until later this evening (its 16:47 for me).

Comment: That is fine, I just appreciate the assistance!  I learn by seeing what is already done and reverse engineering it :-)

Comment: `ShtDest = Array("Early", "Morning", "Afternoon", "DriveTime", "Night")` identifies the five destination worksheets which must exist. `Limit = Array(8, 12, 15, 20)` identifies the boundaries between the worksheets. Amend `ShtDest = Array( ...` if you want a different set of worksheets.  `Limit` must have one less entry that `ShtDest`.

Comment: The comment starting "The purpose of the coding ..." suggests your description and sample coding are misleading. I misread your description and have a date/time in column A rather than column AR. But your description says copy columns A to AQ from Details to the appropriate destination worksheet. In the column you refer to column G. In do not understand.

Comment: There is a limit of 500 characters for a comment.  However, you should add significant clarification to your question which you can edit as often as you wish and which has a limit of 30,000 characters.

Comment: Hey Tony.  I made the sample a lot smaller than the actual document.  I was attempting to provide a mock up of the actual sheet I was using minus all the extra.  Figured I could take the code and adjust the column ID's as needed.  Your formula above works fine (I fixed the errors, they were due to the sheet names).  However, the formula stops working after the "Early" sheet, which seems like it is not continuing the loop.  I put in the formula as it appears in my original post for reference.  Thanks!